# What would be the correct MVC logic to use for a Web Scraper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, web-scraping

I am trying to understand what would be the correct logic to implement a web scraper into a MVC app in Rails. 
I was thinking of a rake task, invoked from a button in the View,that retrieves data and passes it to the Controller.
The Controller sends data to the Model that stores it into the db. 
Is this logic correct or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: It would be better if you write webscraper in background jobs?.

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't know how to store data from there. Let's say I run the task in background and for each page I need to store 10 records in the db. Shall I call the controller.create for each record? Is it right to call the controller from a background rake task?

Comment: From rake you can access model and can directly call any model queries from there. Avoid calling controllers from rake task. And Its better to write a generic library for scrapping.